# Import in plsql developer using sqlldr is very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, import, plsqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have a large .sql file(with 1 Million records) which has insert statements.
this is provided by external system I have no control over.

I have to import this data into my database table, I thought it is a simple job, But Alas how wrong I was.

I am using plsql developer from AllroundAutomations, I went to

> Tools -- Import Tables -- SQL Inserts -- pointed exe to sqlldr.exe,
>   and input to my .sql file with insert statements.

But this process is very slow only inserting around **100 records in a minute**, I was expecting this whole process to take not more than an hour.

Is there a better way to do this, sounds simple to just import all data, but it takes hell lot of time.

P.S: I am a developer and not DBA and not an expert on Oracle, so any help appreciated.

Comment: That seems pretty slow.  You can try sqlplus and using direct-path insert by adding the /*+ APPEND */ hint, but would have to edit the sql and modify every insert statement, I think.

Answer (score 1):

When running massive numbers of INSERT's your should first drop all indexes on the table, then disable all constraints, then run your INSERT statements. You should also modify your script to include a COMMIT after every 1000 records or so. Afterwards re-add your indexes, re-enable all constraints, and gather statistics on that table (DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS).

Best of luck.